# jQuery code refactoring

Tags: jquery

Just wanted some opinions on how to write this code a little better, it is working properly, I'm just trying to learn how to write jQuery better so I wanted some smart peoples opinions. Thanks!

It is checking a shipping address field to see if it contains a PO Box address by looking for variations of "PO" and then displays a warning message after the input if it does contain it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/6RnxG/

```
(function ($) {
    var $shipAddress = $('input[name="user_data[s_address]"]'),
        message = '<div class="message hidden"><p>We <strong>don\'t ship to PO Boxes</strong>. Sorry for the inconvenience.</p></div>';

    $shipAddress.after(message);

    $shipAddress.keyup(function () {
        var $value = $(this).val();

        if ($value === 'po' || $value === 'p.o' || $value === 'PO' || $value === 'P.O') {
            $shipAddress.siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
        } else if ($value === '') {
            $shipAddress.siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: [Please check out codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Minor improvements could be done but really this looks OK. I'd suggest to go on building your application.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Moved question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21445/jquery-code-refactoring

Comment: That's not what we call "move". Now we have 2 identical questions...

Comment: @ferne97: The next time please flag the question so a mod can migrate it instead of reposting it on a different site.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty good code. I see you are adding/removing classes to hide/show elements. Instead of using classes to handle the visibility of elements, you could do `.hide()` and `.show()`. This will add/remove inline style `display: none;`

So, instead of

```
$shipAddress.siblings('.message').removeClass('hidden');
$shipAddress.siblings('.message').addClass('hidden');
```

You can do simply:

```
$shipAddress.siblings('.message').show();
$shipAddress.siblings('.message').hide();
```

So you don't need to write extra css classes. But thats only a minor improvement. Maybe that's only a matter of opinion, but i would prefer  hide and show function.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6RnxG/2/

Comment: Cool, think that is a little more clean, thanks for the input